# Getting Connection object from DataSource in Java

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, datasource

I'm trying to get connection for my web application
I'm using DataSource object and it's injected by @Resource

```
    @Resource(name="jdbc/name")
    private DataSource dataSource;
```

and then in method getConnection() trying to get connection from DataSource object by

```
    private Connection getConnection() {
     Connection con = null;
        try {
            con = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }
```

But my dataSource is null and I'm getting a NullPointerException. By the way, the same code works fine in class, that extends HttpServlet. I need to use this code in simple DBManager class.

Help please, what I have to do?

P.S. I have configured context.xml and web.xml

Comment: the class you are using maybe not managed by Some framework context, how did you get object of this class that method is declared?

Comment: I not using any framework. Method of this class are used by servlet just to get requested data. In servlet I get an instance  'DBManager.getInstance()'  and call methods I need...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowiring only works when Spring creates the bean for you. If you use `new DBManager()` to create the instance, then Spring won't care.

So you need to create or get the application context (which should be configured to contain a `DBManager` bean) and then use that.